Sequence with Parallel as a step
I have a requirement where I want to run parallel events and once all parallel events are done I want to invoke the final endpoint.
So the way I have configured is a Sequence object with first step as Parallel and the last step as final endpoint.
But I can see final endpoint is not invoked however if I move final endpoint before parallel it works. So can anyone help here please how to implement this workflow
apiVersion: flows.knative.dev/v1
kind: Sequence
metadata:
  name: sequence-with-parallel
spec:
  steps:
    - ref:
        apiVersion: flows.knative.dev/v1
        kind: Parallel
        name: parallel-step
    - ref:
        apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
        kind: Service
        name: final-service
  channelTemplate:
    apiVersion: messaging.knative.dev/v1
    kind: InMemoryChannel

Tried running the above implementation but final endpoint is not being invoked however parallel branches are being invoked correctly

It sounds like one of your parallel branches may be failing, which could prevent the final endpoint from being invoked. When an event is sent to a channel (in-memory channel) under the hood but a subscription fails to deliver the event, the channel does not receive the necessary reply, causing the branch to hang until it times out.
To diagnose this, I recommend testing with a simpler setup where the branches are guaranteed to succeed. For instance, configure the parallel branches to forward events to basic event-display services. This will help confirm whether the issue lies within the specific branches or the overall parallel configuration.
Hope this helps!
